# Force SSL Protocol TLSv1.2 with IronPython

Tags: .net, ssl, python-requests, ironpython

I am developing an API wrapper in Python and it works fine with CPython 2.7 and 3.

When I hit an https server from **IronPython**, I get the traceback below

```
IOError: System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
```

I analyzed the packages being sent by the different platforms and notice the only difference was that IronPython was the only one using TSL 1.0 Protocol, and CPython uses TSL 1.2 (see screenshot below)

I used the code below to force Cpython to use TSL 1.0 and got the exact same error, which confirms the issue is with the TSL protocol.
(The code allows me to change the HTTP adapter Protocol consistently)

The problem I am having is, the code below does not seem to have an effect on IronPython, and it continues to use TSL 1.0 on all requests regardless.

Any ideas? Could this be a an IronPython bug?

```
import sys
import platform
print(platform.python_implementation())
print(sys.version_info[0:2])

import ssl
import requests
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
from requests.packages.urllib3.poolmanager import PoolManager

if platform.python_implementation() == 'IronPython':
    print('Setting TSL Protocol')
    import System
    System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12


class ForceTLSV12Adapter(HTTPAdapter):
    """Require TLSv1 for the connection"""
    def init_poolmanager(self, connections, maxsize, block=False):
        # This method gets called when there's no proxy.
        self.poolmanager = PoolManager(
            num_pools=connections,
            maxsize=maxsize,
            block=block,
            ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2,
            # ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1,
        )

    def proxy_manager_for(self, proxy, **proxy_kwargs):
        # This method is called when there is a proxy.
        proxy_kwargs['ssl_version'] = ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2
        return super(ForceTLSV1Adapter, self).proxy_manager_for(proxy, **proxy_kwargs)

s = requests.Session()
s.mount('https://api.unleashedsoftware.com', ForceTLSV12Adapter())
print(s.get("https://api.unleashedsoftware.com"))
```

[image]

PS: I have also tried setting the system wide default protocol, but it does not seem to have any effect:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3140245/update-to-enable-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2-as-a-default-secure-protocols-in

Comment: Seems like this might be a bug in IronPython although it was not confirmed. I worked around it by using .NET's WebRequest Library instead of python's requests

Comment: https://github.com/IronLanguages/ironpython2/issues/227

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code was working properly. The issue was a bug in IronPython:
https://github.com/IronLanguages/ironpython2/issues/227

Comment: so, does the IronPython work with TLS 1.2 now?
or do we need to rewrite and use .NET stuff to work with new encryption?